# Parsing an special xml file using perl

Tags: xml, perl, parsing

I am trying parse below xml file and get the values of bBranch,Branch...

```
<xml-fragment xmlns:con="http://some web link">
  <con:properties>

        <con:string name="bBranch" value="in" export="never" />
        <con:string name="Branch" value="in" export="never" />

        <con:boolean name="cBranch" value="0" export="never" />
  </con:properties>
</xml-fragment>
```

I have tried with XML:LibXML and XML::DOM

Here is a code that i tried:-

```
use XML::DOM;
my $file ="above.xml";
my $parser = XML::DOM::Parser->new();

my $doc = $parser->parsefile($file);

foreach my $entry ($doc->getElementsByTagName('con:properties')) {
        my $parent = $entry->getElementsByTagName('con:string')->item(0)->getFirstChild->getNodeValue;
        print $parent;

}
```

Output:-
Can't call method "getNodeValue" on an undefined value at ./test2.pl line 6.

Am I missing anything or going in any wrong direction?

Please help.
thanks in advance!

**:UPDATE:**

If I were to change my xml file as follows,

```
<xml-fragment xmlns:con="http://some web link">
  <con:properties>           
        <con:string name="Branch" value="Batman" export="never" />
        <con:boolean name="cBranch" value="$Branch" export="never" />
  </con:properties>
</xml-fragment>
```

How can I get the value for `cBranch` such that it will fetch me `$Branch` value `Batman`?

Comment: The XML::LibXML tutorial has a page on [working with namespaces](http://grantm.github.io/perl-libxml-by-example/namespaces.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `$entry->getElementsByTagName('con:string')` returns an array so you need a second loop inside the one that you have. So you can do something like this:

```
foreach my $entry ($doc->getElementsByTagName('con:properties')) {
        foreach my $elem ($entry->getElementsByTagName('con:string')) {
                my $name = $elem->getAttribute('name');
                my $value = $elem->getAttribute('value');
                print "$name = $value\n";
    }
}
```

Note that extracting information like that from xml documents is really tedious, so you may want to look for a solution that allows you to use xpath to access parts of the document. See also choroba's answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to work with namespaces in [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML), you need to use [XML::LibXML::XPathContext](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML::XPathContext):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

use XML::LibXML;

my $dom = 'XML::LibXML'->load_xml(location => 'above.xml');

my $xpc = 'XML::LibXML::XPathContext'->new;
$xpc->registerNs('con', 'http://some%20web%20link');

for my $property ($xpc->findnodes('//con:properties', $dom)) {
    my @names = $xpc->findnodes('con:string/@name', $property);
    say join ' ', map $_->getValue, @names;
}
```

A bit shorter in [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh):

```
open above.xml ;
register-namespace con http://some%20web%20link ;
echo //con:properties/con:string/@name ;
```